# Javascript codigo Usuario Ciafpa

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente codigo js:

```js
var accesoU = () => true
var accesoU = (a,n) => console.log(`Usuario $(n) Acceso $(a)`);
accesoU(acceso,"Ciafpa");
```

deberia retornarme Usuario Ciafpa Acceso true, sin embargo en la consola de desarrollador me aparece:
Usuario $(n) Acceso $(a)

No se por que es.

Alguna idea?
Muchas gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Bueno, empezemos con que tu ejemplo tira error inclusive aqui....

Comment: Para pasar variables a los literales de cadena debes usar `${ variable} `. Estás usando `$( variable) `. Además, estás re declarando la función `accesoU`, por lo tanto se ejecutará la última que has declarado. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias Mauricio, voy a probar del modo en que tu me indicas  ver si puedo hacer que funcione. Pense que era un problema de comillas invertidas.